# Culture based date selection in JQuery Mobile Datebox plugin?

Tags: jquery, mobile, datebox

I am using below jquery mobile datebox plugins for date control in mobile application. It's working fine with default date format. But I want to apply date format based on current culture setting whether it's mobile phone or desktop. Based on device date format, date should be populated in the Date control.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
```

I have tried with below approach.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.mobile.datebox.prototype.options.lang.default, { 'dateFormat': dformat , });
```

But it has two below mentioned limitation due to which I am unable to use this approach. 
1) Not supported on iPhone 3/4 (safari 3.1.1 or below)
2) Date Format which is not compatible with Window format (it uses format like %d-%m-%y etc).

I want to utilize this plugin but it should provide the culture based date format selection.
Please provide your suggestion and let me know if you have any doubt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I really understood your question, but normally you could use the "override" options to inject directly the user culture. In one of my code once I detected the user culture I sue a script like below to do the work: (i update by htis way the header title, the date field order and the dateformat).

In this code the "sDateFormat" set the right pattern following the user culture. And the "currentdatefield" is a jquery variable of a date field in my web form :

```
currentdatefield.data("options", {
                    mode: "datebox",
                    useLang: varuserLocale,
                    useFocus: true,
                    useClearButton: true,
                    useCollapsedBut: true,
                    defaultValue: sDateForDefValue, /* defaultValue : this value must be a string formated in "yyyy-mm-dd" (not a JS object date) */
                    'overrideDateFieldOrder': DateFieldOrder,
                    'overrideHeaderFormat': vardateformat,
                    'overrideDateFormat': sDateFormat   /* Example: "%m/%d/%Y" This date format pattern is directly injected in the field linked */
                });
            });
```

Not sure, it's help you but perhaps.

Comment: Thanks bau, with the help of overrideDateFormat i am able to set preferred date format. Thank you very much.                                I have one more query regarding the JQuery Mobile DateBox. I want to show year selection option in calender control (Basic calendar). So user can easily change the year as currently we have to move month by month. Thanks, Giri

Comment: your second question - 'calUsePickers': true will show both a year and a month picker to jump quickly.

Comment: Additionally, DateBox allows the use of outside files to internationalize the results - http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox2/demos/api/i18n.html gives full details - also, there are quite a few languages/locales already in the repository there.